# python testfixtures.LogCapture not capturing logs

Tags: python, logging, unit-testing

I have a multi-module package in python.  One of the modules is essentially a command line application. We'll call that one the "top level" module.  The other module has three classes in it, which are essentially the backend of the application.

The toplevel module, in the init for it's class, does logging.basicConfig to log debug to file, then adds a console logger for info and above.  The backend classes just use getLogger(classname), because when the application run in full, the backend will be called by the top level command line frontend, so logging will already be configured.

In the Test class (subclassed from unittest.TestCase and run via nose), I simply run testfixtures.LogCapture() in setup, and testfixtures.LogCapture.uninstall_all() in tearDown, and all the logging is captured just fine, no effort.

In the backend test file, I tried to do the same thing.  I run testfixtures.LogCapture in the setup, uninstall_all in the teardown.  However, all the "INFO" level logmessages still print when I'm running unittests for the backend.

Any help on

1) why log capture works for the frontend but not backend

2) an elegant way to be able to log and capture logs in my backend class without explictly setting up logging in those files.

would be amazing.

Comment: Turns out if I run either one of my test files together (one file for each of the modules), then I have no logging issues.  Only when I run them together do I get log lines printed to console.

Comment: I also found that if I rename the backend test file to something that runs before the frontend, it works.  My current guess is that since basicConfig is not over-rideable, doing the basicConfig somehow inherits a stream that is not used by the second test file, and therefore doesn't work.  I will experiment with configuring my loggers in a different fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by setting 'disable_existing_loggers' to False when reconfiguring the Logger: the previous logger was disabled and it was preventing it from propagating the logs to the RootLogger.